# How to map an immutable collection with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate as a JPA implementation, and I want to load a relationship as an immutable collection.

Let's take an example of an `Employer` parent entity that has an `employees` child collection.

What can be done to instruct JPA to load an immutable `employees` collection?

Comment: What's the problem in returning `Collections.unmodifiableSet(employees)` from the getter of your association?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using lombok for generating getter method and don't want to create getter method manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use the [@Immutable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) Hibernate specific annotation:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
   @Immutable
   List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Another option is to clone the collection prior to returning it:

   Assuming you have a List of employees, you can map it like this:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
   List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
       return org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone(employees);
   }
   ```

   By omitting the `setter` and having the `getter` return only a copy of the backed list, you can achieve immutability. Using deep-copy cloning (e.g.  `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils`) ensures the whole entity graph is cloned and therefore decoupled from the managed parent entity.

Comment: I will go with @Immutable for the time being but I was looking for pure JPA solution for this problem.

Comment: IMO second solution is not an optimal solution for global data which is accessed frequently as cloning will both impact performance as well as consume more memory.